# Attribute Missing from linq query result

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-sql

Please find below the linq query

```
var result = (
    from sd in students
    select sd.Student_ID
  ).Except(
    from m in query1 
    select m.Student_ID
  ).ToList();
```

from this query I am getting the exact results. Now I want to populate other data of students so what I have done is wrote other linq query. Below here, **But I am not getting *r.Student_ID* attribute to compare with students table.** Intellisense not giving r.Student_ID. Please help!

```
var finalResult = (
    from sd in dbcDefaulter.Student_Details 
    from r in result 
    where r == sd.Student_ID
    orderby sd.Student_ID
    select new { sd.Student_ID, sd.Name, sd.Class, sd.Section, sd.F_Name, sd.F_Mobile }
  ).Distinct().ToList();
```

Please find Complete `designer.cs` [here](http://pastebin.com/Rs4B1PkF)

Part of the Student_Details class looks like this:

```
[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.TableAttribute(Name="dbo.Student_Detail")]
public partial class Student_Detail
{
    private int _Student_ID;
    private string _Class;
    private string _Section;
    private string _Session;
    private string _Name;
    private System.Nullable<System.DateTime> _B_Date;
    private string _E_Mail;
    private string _Gender;
    private string _F_Name;


    //From Jesse: Please insert the property definition for Student and/or Students, and/or Student_ID here if available.
}
```

Part of the `get set` properties looks like this:

```
public DefaulterDataContext(System.Data.IDbConnection connection, System.Data.Linq.Mapping.MappingSource mappingSource) : 
                base(connection, mappingSource)
        {
            OnCreated();
        }

        public System.Data.Linq.Table<Student_Detail> Student_Details
        {
            get
            {
                return this.GetTable<Student_Detail>();
            }
        }

        public System.Data.Linq.Table<Fees_Due> Fees_Dues
        {
            get
            {
                return this.GetTable<Fees_Due>();
            }
        }
```

Please find the definition of `query1` and `students` that we have used in very first query that is `result`. So `query1` is -

```
var query1 = (from fd in dbcDefaulter.Fees_Dues
                          join sd in dbcDefaulter.Student_Details on Convert.ToInt32(fd.Student_ID) equals sd.Student_ID
                          where fd.Session == GlobalVariables.Session && (fd.Month.Contains(cmbMonth.SelectedItem.ToString()))
                          orderby fd.Student_ID
                          select new { sd.Student_ID, fd.Month, fd.Session }).Distinct();
```

and `students` is -

```
var students = (from sd in dbcDefaulter.Student_Details
                        select sd).ToList();
```

Comment: Sorry ;(, I am newbie to linq. I didnt understand what do you mean, could you please give me a sample /example?

Comment: Please edit it into your question instead.

Comment: What is `list` as in `from r in list`? What is its type?

Comment: Do you mean type of `r`? I want the `result` query to return list of `student_ID` which satisfies the condition. so that I can use the list of `Student_ID` to filter further results as I have used in `finalResult` query in my question. But I am not getting `r.Student_ID` :( :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of joining, you could consider using `List<T>.Contains(aValue)`; this also solves the issue you're getting with the `Instance argument: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<AnonymousType#1>' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable<int>'` in the other solution provided:

```
var result = (
    from sd in students
    select sd.Student_ID
  ).Except(
    from m in query1 
    select m.Student_ID
  ).ToList();

var finalResult = (
    from sd in dbcDefaulter.Student_Details 
    where result.Contains(sd.Student_ID)
    orderby sd.Student_ID
    select 
       new { sd.Student_ID, sd.Name, sd.Class, sd.Section, sd.F_Name, sd.F_Mobile}
).Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: I am getting error that sd does not contain definition for Student. Getting  error at `sd.Student.Student_ID`

Comment: I shared the definition class above

Comment: I have shared the `get set property` of the class in the Question

Comment: I want to attach my complete code file so that you can go through it, could you please tell me how to do that? and where to do?

Comment: Put them on pastebin.com and post the link(s).

Comment: Second solution works as expected... Thanks alot for your valuable help and support.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information that you have provided this is how you should update the code:

```
 // Updated first query to return the Student_ID in an anonymous class.
 var result = (from sd in students select new {Student_ID = sd.Student_ID})
     .Except(from m in query1 select m.Student_ID).ToList();

 // Updated second query to use Join statement
 var finalResult = (
     from sd in dbcDefaulter.Student_Details
     join r in result on sd.Student_ID equals r.Student_ID
     orderby sd.Student_ID
     select new {sd.Student_ID, sd.Name, sd.Class, sd.Section, sd.F_Name, sd.F_Mobilez
 ).Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: with out giving reason of reducing the answer is called jealous. It will lead  you nowhere....

Comment: Do me a favor @jessehouwing start reading about what other has to say rather what you know. You have not even saw my answer. You might be master but soon or later you will go cross the same path. Anyways, good luck.

Comment: Hi Codebased, This is response to your soultion. The solution you have provided not working. **Its says that r does not contain definition for Student_ID**. Could you please help me?

Comment: Did you made sure that you wrote first query like this: var result = (from sd in students
            select new {StudentID = sd.Student_ID}).Except(from m in query1
                select m.Student_ID).ToList();

Comment: Sorry for overlooking the solution :(. I have corrected my `result` query. After that I am getting compilation Error that **Expected contextual keyword 'equals'**  and red underlined the `orderby` keyword in  `finalresult` query

Comment: Please be cool, you both are experts, its just matter of misundertanding. I am really sorry for that.

Comment: @SandeepKushwah please replace == with equals and rest is same.

Comment: @SandeepKushwah I have modified my query above

Comment: `result` query throwing compile time error. Here it is
`Instance argument: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<AnonymousType#1>' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable<int>'`